# Trying and failing to set innerHTML for DIV inside opener window from popup window

Tags: javascript, popup, innerhtml, window.opener

I got a problem with this little code from a popup

```
function edit(titre,texte) {
    window.opener.document.getElementById('corp').innerHTML +=
            '<h2>'+titre.value+'</h2> <p>'+texte.value+'</p>';
    window.close();
}
```

Nothing happens when this script is launched. I want to change the contents of `myDiv` in the opener window.

I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Please specify your setup more clearly. I don't think you will be receiving much help otherwise. Can you tell us what is reported in your developer tools' JavaScript console?

Comment: I would guess that you cannot directly manipulate the DOM of the opener window from within a popup window due to security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Opener is property of the window, not of the document, so it should be:

```
window.opener.document...
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Console? How do you open the popup window? Can you copy the output of console.log(window.opener.document.getElementById('corp'))?